# What would cause HTML table cells to open Android phone pad?

Tags: android, html, mobile

I have a simple table no links just some class tags on certain days.  It is used to display the days in a month.  On an Android phone , it for some reason is taking a few of the days of the month and is opening the phone pad.  The Android version is 2.3.4.  All my html is valid and conforming.  Has anyone else run into this?  Any thoughts as to work arounds.

Here is the full example that has this issue.

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html>
<head><title>Untitled</title></head>
<body>
<table cellspacing="0">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>
                &laquo;
            </th>
            <th colspan="5">
                <span>January&nbsp;2012</span>
            </th>
            <th>
                &raquo;
            </th>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <th>
                Mon
            </th>
            <th>
                Tue
            </th>
            <th>
                Wed
            </th>
            <th>
                Thu
            </th>
            <th>
                Fri
            </th>
            <th>
                Sat
            </th>
            <th>
                Sun
            </th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        <tr>
            <td>
                26
            </td>
            <td>
                27
            </td>
            <td>
                28
            </td>
            <td>
                29
            </td>
            <td>
                30
            </td>
            <td>
                31
            </td>
            <td>
                1
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>
                2
            </td>
            <td>
                3
            </td>
            <td>
                4
            </td>
            <td>
                5
            </td>
            <td>
                6
            </td>
            <td>
                7
            </td>
            <td>
                8
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>
                9
            </td>
            <td>
                10
            </td>
            <td>
                11
            </td>
            <td>
                12
            </td>
            <td>
                13
            </td>
            <td>
                14
            </td>
            <td>
                15
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>
                16
            </td>
            <td>
                17
            </td>
            <td>
                18
            </td>
            <td>
                19
            </td>
            <td>
                20
            </td>
            <td>
                21
            </td>
            <td>
                22
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>
                23
            </td>
            <td>
                24
            </td>
            <td>
                25
            </td>
            <td>
                26
            </td>
            <td>
                27
            </td>
            <td>
                28
            </td>
            <td>
                29
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>
                30
            </td>
            <td>
                31
            </td>
            <td>
                1
            </td>
            <td>
                2
            </td>
            <td>
                3
            </td>
            <td>
                4
            </td>
            <td>
                5
            </td>
        </tr>
    </tbody></table></body></html>
```

Comment: Please post your HTML so we can take a look.

Comment: Added the full html page.  This code exibits the behavior.  If you click on any of the days it opens the phone pad with a couple of the days around the clicked day in the phone pad.

Answer (score 1):

I found a work around there is a meta tag that you can set for telephone detection.

```
 <meta name="format-detection" content="telephone=no">
```

Thank you everyone for your help.

Answer (score 0):

Without your code it's difficult to say, but it is most likely because in certain instances, the numbers in the cells get identified as being phone numbers which the Android system automatically creates a hyperlink to the phone application.  Android also does this with email addresses and a few other things that follow a typical structure.

Comment: Hi thanks for the response.  I do understand that it does this automatically.  But I thought it did it when the numbers were some how together and not in seperated html elements.  Do you happen to know if there is some way to decorate the html to not allow this?

Comment: I cannot reproduce the problem on Android 2.3.5 using the exact code you posted, and I wonder why it would open the phone pad, even if it recognized something as phone number, unless some action was taken by the user. Do you observe the problem with a document containing just the code you posted? If not, please try to provide a minimal document that still exhibits the problem.

Comment: Yep the device I have seen it on is a droid bionic from verizon which is running 2.3.4.

Comment: I updated the source to the full html page that this is happening on.